# Flask SQLAlchemy does not commit until App ends

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask

I've started my session like so:

```
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql://mydatabase'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

And I'm Adding entries to my database like so:

```
db.session.add(user(name, password))
db.session.commit()
```

Immediately after I add it, I render a new template. When the template's rendered, it should include the data I've just added, but it doesn't. However, when I end my app with a ctrl-c, then restart it, the data I've added now shows.

The data is submitted using a GET. The arguments are obtained using `flask.request.args.get` and it gets the name and password. Then the data is added using the `db.session.add` thing above.

After the `db.session.add` is done, the data is obtained from the entire database like so:

```
users = []
for userentry in user.query.all():
    users.append(userentry.name)
```

In the template:

```
{% for name in users %}
    <p>{{name}}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Then template is rendered using: `return render_template('my_page.html', users=users)`

Comment: Not sure if your question is very clear. HOw are you inserting the data ? Do you have a form in the template to insert the data using POST ? please post the entire code of the view function that has the form entry along with template rendering.

Answer (score 0):

It seems I've been using an older design pattern that I found on the Flask Mega Tutorial. I solved my problem by opening up individual sessions for adding data. http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/session.html